# How do you stop the sliding of rigid body objects?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have some simple tile like boxes that fall onto a plane. The tile boxes have a rigid body shape of "Box". However even when I think the simulation would be done, the boxes continue to slide off at shallow angle. What attributes in the rigid body physics controls how much an object grips another object. I tried increasing the friction of all the objects to 1 with no effect. Also turned off bounciness and increased damping. But the objects continue to slide until the point that they are all lying flat on the plane. I would think that friction would stop this.

I recreated the scene from scratch and set the friction of all the objects to 1 before running the simulation.  Below is the blend file that I created.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure the plane and all the objects have increased friction

Comment: As I said in my question. I've tried increasing the friction of all objects to 1 and that doesn't stop the sliding.

Comment: @deltaray Did you rebake the animation after changing the friction value? 'Cause it really should work

Comment: I've edited my question to include a copy of the blend file after recreating the scene from scratch.

Comment: Is this problem resolved? I am facing similar issues and not sure of how to set the params.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *Enable Deactivation* option and adjusting it's parameters:

[image]

It also helps to have the collision objects set as *Passive*.

What will also increase the simulation accuracy is number of simulation steps:

[image]

The more steps the less sliding in the end and the more accurate simulation (this is 5000 steps):

[image]

---

If you don't want to increase steps, you can also *Bake the simulation to keyframes* with Object > Animation > Bake Action and delete the keyframes in *Dope Sheet Editor* that you don't want.

---

You can also keyframe the animation tag on the rigid body to be checked in the start and in the end of simulation:

[image]

This will enable you to control the position and bypass simulation when the tag is on. Notice that during simulation the location (in N panel) of bricks doesn't change from starting position. You need to get the end location and rotation from `word_matrix` in the *Console*:

```
bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world.translation
bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world.to_euler()
```

And you keyframe the starting position and the end position.